# SQL LIKE %?% странно выбирает данные из БД

Tags: php, sql, like

В $_GET['key'] из формы передается строка символов введенных с клавиатуры.
В БД нужно найти все записи, в которых встречается такая подстрока. Запрос написал, но он как-то не правильно он работает: вводим в поле "e", запрос находит "t**e**st" - все верно. Вводим "s", "es", "t" и т.д. - запрос ничего не находит. В чем может быть проблема?

```
if(isset($_GET['key'])){
$key = $_GET['key'];
if(strlen($key) > 0){
    if($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE 'key' LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')"))
    {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $key);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($res_id, $res_key);
    while($stmt->fetch())
        echo "<div>:".htmlspecialchars($res_key)."</div>";
    }
    else
        echo $db->error;
}
```

}

Comment: WHERE 'key' вы ищите имнно в этом слове. Либо без кавычек, либо косые ковычки как в названии таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой запрос:

```
if(strlen($key) > 0){

    $search = "%$key%";

    if($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE `key` LIKE :search"))
    {
    $stmt->bind_param(':search', $search);
    $stmt->execute();
```

У меня сработал.